# SSIS Main Package throwing Error : Package Failed Validation From Execute Package Task

Tags: ssis

i have a Main Package and 2 child packages(Load and Export). i have both child packages on the server in shared folder. when i execute Main Package its giving me the following Error for one of the Child package.

Error: Error 0xC0012050 while loading package file "\mhfile02\DIRFILEDEV\CHG77253\SSIS Packages\AaeAutoenrollee_Load.dtsx". Package failed validation from the ExecutePackage task. The package cannot run. .

Can anybody tell me what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Almost anything. It could be that there's an error in the package. It could be that the package can't find something it needs to find like a connections or a config file or table.  Failing validation is a very generic error in SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the package via SQL Server Agent?

Try running the child packages individually, it may be throwing other errors. If the package runs without error, the problem is probably on the Main package settings.

Some questions that may help you?
1. when you loaded the packages to the server, did you set any Protection Level (eg encrypt sensitive data with key, user key, etc?) setting these can make a package fail loading when run via SQL Server Agent
2. Try adding /msdb/ to the path of the child package.

Answer (score 1):

From one day to another, I got this error in Visual Studio / SSDT too (VS 2013, with SSIS 2014). Note: I have project deployment model, not package deployment.
I have ProtectionLevel = EncryptSensitiveWithPassword.

In the master package, on all package execution tasks, I had to retype the password for the sub-packages again. After that, it worked again. I guess the master package had some corruption, no idea why.

Greetings, 
Roli

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting in the child package to an Excel file, 
and you set on the child solution property page 
Under - 
"Configuration Propeties"
"Debugging"
the variable "Run64BitRunTime" = False
You have to do it also on the Parent Package!

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that your child package will not pass the validation. Check your child package to see if there's any task inside that does not pass the validation (a red cross appears beside it).

Maybe you have something being dynamically created that is used in such task (like constructing the connection string at runtime for some connection manager). Try set this task's DelayValidation property to True.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting in the child package to an Excel file, then set `DelayValidation` = `False` on the child package excel connection manager.